# How to use the /x regex option in R

Tags: r, regex, pcre

*Update:*

Leaving this here for trivia, but the answer in the duplicated question is *much* prettier.

I would like to nicely-format my regex in R by using the `/x` option. I understand this is a PCRE option, so I'm passing `perl=TRUE` to enable that language style.

But the regex is returning no matches. No compile error, but no matches.

Here is my test code:

```
expr <- "# match any year
([0-9]{4})
(
  # January-September
  (?:0[1-9])
  # OR October - December
  |(?:1[0-2])
)
(
  # First nine days of the month.
  (?:0[1-9])
  # Next twenty days of the month.
  |(?:[1-2][0-9])
  # Last two days of the month.
  |(?:(?<!02)3[0-1])
)
# A hyphen and then any four digits.
-([0-9]{4})/x"

print(
  grep(
    expr, 
    c(
      "20190916-9999",
      "20041009-1234",
      "19981231-4321",
      "20420230-0000"
    ),
    perl=TRUE,
    value=TRUE
  )
)
```

The first three strings should match, but the fourth shouldn't.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can build a commented regex like so:

```
expr <- "(?# 
# match any year
)([0-9]{4})(?#
)(?#
  # January-September
  )((?:0[1-9])(?#
  # OR October - December
  )|(?:1[0-2])(?#
))(?#
  # First nine days of the month.
  )((?:0[1-9])(?#
  # Next twenty days of the month.
  )|(?:[1-2][0-9])(?#
  # Last two days of the month.
  )|(?:(?<!02)3[0-1])(?#
))(?#
# A hyphen and then any four digits.
)-([0-9]{4})"

print(
  grep(
    expr, 
    c(
      "20190916-9999",
      "20041009-1234",
      "19981231-4321",
      "20420230-0000"
    ),
    perl=TRUE,
    value=TRUE
  )
)
```

The parentheses are daunting, but it might still be better than zero-whitespace regex. Thanks for the tip, GKi!

Comment: Ha, we both asked questions about it. Duplication on duplication.

Comment: We did, @MichaelCrenshaw. That's teamwork! I appreciate your interest in helping me. Truly grateful because it turns out just putting `(?x)` in front of my RegEx does the trick, and this *revolutionizes* my development of Regular Expressions. It is so much easier to see how they work, both while writing them and when maintaining them. It's like night and day.

Comment: @JaiJeffryes Fantastic! Enjoying your album on Spotify, so we'll call it an even trade. :-)

Comment: And an upvote from me. :)